# Can Windows damage a mounted TrueCrypt drive on shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, truecrypt

I have Windows 7, and I have one encrypted [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt) drive which is auto mounted on Windows logon with a script. But on Windows shutdown I don't use a script to dismount the drive before shutting down Windows. Can leaving the drive mounted when shutting down Windows, somehow damage the data on the encrypted drive?

Comment: You should dismount the drive before you restart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TrueCrypt automatically dismounts its volumes when Windows is shutting down.
(i.e. the user is "logged off" and there is a setting for auto-dismount when this happens.)

If you hibernate your PC and want the volume to dismount you can also set this in the options.

[image]

---

**Edit:**
Please note that when mounting a volume via a script you need to make sure **TrueCrypt.exe** is also loaded. This is the "TrueCrypt Background Task" and is responsible for the Auto-dismount and more.

**TrueCrypt Background Task**:
When the main TrueCrypt window is closed, the TrueCrypt Background Task takes care of the following tasks/functions:

- Hot keys
- Auto-dismount (e.g., upon logoff, inadvertent host device removal, time-out, etc.)
- Auto-mount of favorite volumes
- Notifications (e.g., when damage to hidden volume is prevented)
- Tray icon

See also http://andryou.com/truecrypt/docs/background-task.php

You can run `truecrypt /q background` to start it directly in the background.

Comment: Yes, but i am using TrueCrypt in portable mode and i am mounting/dismounting volumes from command prompt, so TrueCrypt is not running when Windows is shutting down.

Comment: Are you sure TrueCrypt isn't running as process in the background. If it's not then you shouldn't be able to access that volume. Try looking in the taskmanager (processes-tab) for a process with the name TrueCrypt.exe. It should be there.

Comment: Correction... You're right. When ending the TrueCrypt process I still have access to the volume. I'll need to investigate further. I wonder what is responsible for writing to the truecrypt-file at that point.

Comment: @peter7558 Yes, you need the TrueCrypt.exe running for the auto-dismount function. See my edited answer. If you don't want the TrueCrypt.exe loaded you need to dismount manually before shutdown.

Comment: @peter7558 You can run `truecrypt /q background` to start it directly in the background.